# Imagebutton onclick not working in updatepanel, How can I make it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, imagebutton

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"   
 runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate> 
     <asp:ImageButton ID="imagebutton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image.jpg" Width="125" 
     Height="125"  onclick="imagebutton1_Click" />
     <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" ontick="timer1_Tick" />
     <asp:Label ID="label1" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If I don't use an update panel the whole page refreshes.

```
protected void imagebutton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e){
    string link = label1.Text;
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OPEN", "window.open(" + link +   
    ",'mywindow','width=200,height=200,');", true);
}
```

This is the variable "link" here in the timer handler

```
Random r = new Random();

if (datatable1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int randomnumber = r.Next(0, i);
    DataRow datarow1= datatable1.Rows[randomnumber ];
    imagebutton1.ImageUrl = (String)datarow1["image"];
    imagebutton1.DataBind();
    label1.Text = (String)datarow1["Link"];
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code, part of your `Page_Load` method and the setup of the ImageButton settings (maybe from the designer source file)?

Comment: This is your 12th question,in the meantime you should have noticed that a question should contain more than a half-sentence and a "not working". Please provide the exact error/wrong behaviour and the relevant code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it does not call the onclick event in the codebehind.

Comment: Why are posting back to server at all to open a popup on clientside? You simply need to use [OnclientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick.aspx) to open that popup. Remember to `return false` after that javascript since otherwise the page posts back (or use a HTML-Image and it's onclick event). Edit: Have you set a breakpoint in the clickevent handler to see if it gets called?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I need it in the server as I need to obtain the images and the links from a database.

Comment: @seesharp: Where are you initializing theses variables like `link`? The only correct place is in the buttonclick-handler and not in page_load. Show us your page_load as well.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because its the buttonclick handler which is not firing while the image is in the updatepanel. Outside the updatepanel it works fine, but it refreshes the whole page which I don't want. What I am simply looking to do is be able to fire the imagebutton handler when the imagebutton is in the updatepanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to just add postback triggers as shown below in the updatepanel to make it work.

```
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger  ControlID="ImageButton"/>
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say since you didn't really include a question, but if you want a piece of client side code to run when an UpdatePanel refreshes, use the client side [`pageLoad()` method](http://encosia.com/simplify-aspnet-ajax-client-side-page-initialization/).

Also, you are using a server side event to do a client side operation. Use the `OnClientClick` handler instead:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imagebutton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image.jpg" Width="125" 
    Height="125"  OnClienClick="return openPopUp(this.href);" />

function openPopUp(link)
{
   window.open(this.href,'mywindow','width=200,height=200,');
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I would like to call the imagebutton1_Click when i click on the imagebutton it is not firing

Comment: I need it in the server as I need to obtain the images and the links from a database and the onclientclick still does not work within the updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to `UpdateMode="Always"`